# Einstein notation - Favre

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, notation, representation-theory, index-notation

I recently started using Einstein notation a lot from this paper [AGARD-R-819](https://www.sto.nato.int/publications/AGARD/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fpublications%2FAGARD%2FAGARD%2DR%2D819&FolderCTID=0x0120D5200078F9E87043356C409A0D30823AFA16F60B00B8BCE98BB37EB24A8258823D6B11F157&View=%7B7E9C814C-056A-4D31-8392-7C6752B2AF2B%7D). However, I was never formally introduced to it academically. I was wondering if someone here could help me validate my confusion. I have 3 questions.

1.
$$\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} \; + \; \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}$$

From the equation, what impact does it have if you switch the $i$ & $j$. From my understanding, the answer is a scalar anyways so the order of the sum should not matter. I'm I correct?

2.The Kronecker delta basically tells us to sum the trace of a tensor.

$$\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k} \: \delta_{ij}$$

So here the $k$ subscript is going to be k = 1, 2, 3. But why can't we write $j$ instead?

3.Similarly from 2,

$$\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k} \: \delta_{ij} * \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$$

Is it still going to be the sum of the trace for both derivative term?

Comment: RE: 2) I think that as a matter of fact, you CAN write j instead, but it's only because both forms just happen to evaluate to the trace.  If you didn't know that $\delta_{i,j}$ was zero everywhere that $i \neq j$, then it would be a mistake to just use $j$, because you'd be skipping over a bunch of things that "could" be non-zero.

Comment: has you tried to search information using google? There is a lot of sources explaining Einstein conventions, by example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) there is a lot of information and, what is more important, bibliography about it

Answer (score 0):

1. The summation convention does not apply here, as there are not two repeated indices *in one term*. That is, $\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}$ is just an object with two indices.
2. Here, $k$ is repeated twice, so we do have summation. Indeed,
   $$\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k} \delta_{ij} = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} \delta_{ij} + \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2} \delta_{ij} + \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3} \delta_{ij}$$
   (assuming dimension $3$). This is again just an object with two indices, whose value depends on $i$ and $j$. If $i=1, j=1$, then it evaluates to $\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2} + \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}$, and if $i=1, j=0$, then it evaluates to $0$. We could not label $k$ to $j$ and still use Einstein notation as then there would be three repeated indices in one term, which is generally not allowed (as it is ill-defined).
3. $i$, $j$ and $k$ are all repeated twice so we have summation over all three in $$\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k} \delta_{ij} \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}.$$
   Using the sifting property $\delta_{ij} a_j = a_i$, the expression is the same as $$\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k} \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i} = \left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i}\right)^2.$$